# meaning of "tend to"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I know the primary meaning of "tend to" - have a tendency to~ / If something tends to happen, it usually happens or it often happens.

But in this context (this is from my English reading book) 
-> Too many of your fellow students are too busy complaining about the teachers and the system to tend to their studies, which, after all, are the primary reason for being in school.

according to the explanation from the book, here meaninf of " tend to" is same as "devoted" 
But I couldnt find this meaning in my dictionary..(korean-English)

so my question is that does the meaning of "devoted" in "tend to" commonly use in academic writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/tend)

**to tend** [verb]

> 1. to be likely to behave in a particular way or have a particular characteristic
> 2. **to care for something** or someone

**devoted** [adjective]

> **extremely** loving and loyal

I wouldn't use devoted in your case. It establishes a grade (extremely), that is not present in the level of careness that denotes to tend.

Students should care about its lessons but they do not have to be absolutely devoted to them.

Let me recommend you to use online English dictionaries instead of Korean/English ones. You will improve your English skills. :-)